# Sonarqube issue "refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 18 to the 15 allowed." Rewrite code block

Tags: javascript, typescript, sonarqube

Sonarqube have issues with the following code, giving the warning "refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 18 to the 15 allowed."

Not sure what I need to do, or how I can refactor the function to meet the criterium of "Cognitive complexity max 15". Any help?

```
this.register(
        VehicleConceptSpecification,
        Action.Execute,
        async (_vehicle: VehicleInfo,
               conceptSpec: { result: TestConceptSpecification[] },
               controlRecord: Value | undefined,
               userPartnerId: string,
               onProgress?: (progress: number) => void): Promise<IVehicleData<RunRoutineResponse>> => {
          await this.setup;
          if (!this.productCommunicationClient?.canExecuteRoutine()) {
            return Promise.reject('Client is not able to execute routine');
          }
          if (conceptSpec.result[0]?.node == null) {
            return Promise.reject('concept specification does not contain node identifier');
          }
          if (conceptSpec.result[0]?.onVehicleTest?.value == null) {
            return Promise.reject(
              'Concept specification does not contain onVehicleTest with value');
          }
          const nodes = await this.readNodes([this.convertNodeIdentifier(conceptSpec.result[0].node)]);
          if (nodes?.length !== 1) {
            return Promise.reject('Failed to read node');
          }
          const iso14229routine: Iso14229RoutineSpecification = {
            communicationProtocol: CommunicationProtocol.Iso14229,
            value: controlRecord,
            node: nodes[0],
            partnerIdentifier: userPartnerId,
            diagnosticObjectIdentifier: conceptSpec.result[0].onVehicleTest.value
          };
          const observer = await this.productCommunicationClient.executeRoutine(iso14229routine);
          const result: RunRoutineResponse = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let routineResult: RunRoutineResponse | undefined;
            observer.subscribe({
              next: ({ progress, response }) => {
                if (onProgress != null) {
                  onProgress(progress);
                }
                if (response != null) {
                  routineResult = response;
                }
          });
```

Comment: you need to remove the amount of if's

Comment: one easy way is to split this in multiple smaller functions